# in python how to get "RPi.GPIO" event callback from asyncio.gather async task loop

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-asyncio, gpio, python-3.10

I have come to know asyncio for several days and implementing in raspbaerry pi board code for lora sx127x module.

**I want to know how to implement an add gpio event callback in my asyncio run (main) loop.** I know that gpio event is being run in different thread in background and not in asyncio loop. I want to be able to make "on_rx_done" working in asyncio code.

Any documentation suggestion or hint will be extremely beneficial. I have reat asyncio.event, asyncio.loop, asyncio.future from python documents but can't decide which will be effective here. If possible I would like to use high level asyncio api from [here](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/asyncio-api-index.html)

here is my base [reference](https://github.com/mayeranalytics/pySX127x/blob/master/rx_cont.py) code which works synchronously. I want to convert it to convert it to compatible with asyncio module.

I was expecting to get get "async _dio0()" callback which calls "async on_rx_done()" which fills "payload" in queue_1 and then I start processing "payload" it in "make_json_string" function and so on.

in case need to help understanding context. here is simplified version of my current code.

1. used contex var for passing queue_1 between asyncio loops
2. tried to set asyncio.Event.set but failed
3. used to get this error "<_ "UnixSelectorEventLoop" running=True closed=False debug=False>" on every receive event but now response happens.

```
import asyncio
from SX127x.LoRa import *
from SX127x.LoRaArgumentParser import LoRaArgumentParser
from SX127x.board_config import BOARD
from contextvars import ContextVar

class LoRaRcvCont(LoRa):

   server_status = False

   def __init__(self, verbose=False):
        super(LoRaRcvCont, self).__init__(verbose)

        # here bellow add event function is called
        # GPIO.add_event_detect(dio_number, GPIO.RISING, callback=callback)
        # equivalant GPIO.add_event_detect(gpio_4, GPIO.RISING, callback=_dio0)

        self.set_mode(MODE.SLEEP)
        self.set_dio_mapping([0] * 6)

   async def _dio0(self, channel):#override callback function as async function
        # DIO0 00: RxDone
        # DIO0 01: TxDone
        # DIO0 10: CadDone
        print('_dio')
        if self.dio_mapping[0] == 0:
            await self.on_rx_done()
        elif self.dio_mapping[0] == 1:
            await self.on_tx_done()
        elif self.dio_mapping[0] == 2:
            await self.on_cad_done()
        else:
            raise RuntimeError("unknown dio0mapping!")

    async def on_rx_done(self):#override function as async function
        print("\nLoRa RxDone")
        await asyncio.sleep(.01)
        if self.dio_mapping[0] == 0:
            print("LoRa RxDone")
            self.clear_irq_flags(RxDone=1)
            payload = self.read_payload(nocheck=True)

            # add task in queue_1 if payload not empty
            if len(payload) > 0:
                temp_queue_1 = queue_1_var.get()
                try:
                    print('queue_1 put task, start')
                    await temp_queue_1.put(payload)
                except:  # pylint: disable=bare-except
                    print('ERROR in put queue_1.')
                finally:
                    print('queue_1 put task,  done')
            # return payload

    async def make_json_string(self, queue_1, queue_2):
        while True:
            # print("make_json_string")
            # get a unit of work
            # print("queue_1 get = ")
            payload = await queue_1.get()

            # Notify the queue that the "work item" has been processed.
            queue_1.task_done()

    async def start(self, queue_1):
        self.reset_ptr_rx()
        self.set_mode(MODE.RXCONT)
        count = 0
        #payload = [205, 171, 1, 82, 77, 49, 48, 48, 48, 48]

        # asyncio.get_event_loop()
        while True:

            await asyncio.sleep(3)
            # await queue_1.put(payload)

            count = count + 1
            print("loop" + str(count))

async def main():

    BOARD.setup()

    # create the shared queue
    queue_1 = asyncio.Queue()
    queue_1_var.set(queue_1)


    # Create an Event object.
    event = asyncio.Event()

    lora = lora_config_setup()

    try:
        print("asyncio loop starts ...")
        await asyncio.gather(
            asyncio.create_task(lora.start(queue_1)),
            #asyncio.Event.set(lora._dio0(None)),
            asyncio.create_task(lora.make_json_string(queue_1),
        )
        # )

        print("main done")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.stdout.flush()
        print("")
        sys.stderr.write("KeyboardInterrupt\n")
    finally:
        sys.stdout.flush()
        print("")
        lora.set_mode(MODE.SLEEP)

    debug_print(lora)
    BOARD.teardown()

########################
# code starts from here
#########################
queue_1_var = ContextVar('queue_1')
asyncio.run(main())
print("code finished")
```

update 23 mar 2023:

I'm using async polling for the GPIO input method until a proper solution for GPIO event callback is found.

```
...
class LoRaRcvCont(LoRa):

    server_status = False

    def __init__(self, verbose=False):
        super(LoRaRcvCont, self).__init__(verbose)
        self.set_mode(MODE.SLEEP)
        self.set_dio_mapping([0] * 6)
    async def async_dio0(self, channel):
        # DIO0 00: RxDone
        # DIO0 01: TxDone
        # DIO0 10: CadDone

        print('in _dio')
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(.1) 
            if GPIO.input(channel): #irq pin high
                
                #self.get_dio_mapping() #get dio mapping
                print('got interrupt _dio')
                print(f"rx_done: {self.dio_mapping[0]}")
                if self.dio_mapping[0] == 0:
                    await self.on_rx_done()
                elif self.dio_mapping[0] == 1:
                    await self.on_tx_done()
                elif self.dio_mapping[0] == 2:
                    await self.on_cad_done()
                else:
                    raise RuntimeError("unknown dio0mapping!")
            else:
                pass
...

#main asyncio coroutine here all code is executed
async def main():

    BOARD.setup()

    # create the shared queue
    queue_1 = asyncio.Queue()
    queue_1_var.set(queue_1)


    # Create an Event object.
    event = asyncio.Event()

    lora = lora_config_setup()
    # http_server_check() # was using request module

    try:
        print("asyncio loop starts ...")
        await asyncio.gather(
            asyncio.create_task(lora.start(queue_1)),
            # asyncio.create_task(lora.on_rx_done()),
            # asyncio.create_task(lora.on_tx_done),
            asyncio.create_task(lora.async_dio0(BOARD.DIO0)),
            asyncio.create_task(lora.make_json_string(queue_1)),
        )

        print("main done")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.stdout.flush()
        print("")
        sys.stderr.write("KeyboardInterrupt\n")
    finally:
        sys.stdout.flush()
        print("")
        lora.set_mode(MODE.SLEEP)

    debug_print(lora)
    BOARD.teardown()

queue_1_var = ContextVar('queue_1')

asyncio.run(main())
print("code finished")
```

Comment: I have found this [solution](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54514/implement-a-gpio-function-with-a-callback-calling-a-asyncio-method) which might work fine till 3.9 but loop parameter is deprcrated in python3.10. so want answer to convert form loop to asynio.run or asyncio.gather format. any suggestion make this solution work in python3.10